# How to save a Project Gutenberg book to Pocket?

Tags: pocket, project-gutenberg

When I try to save http://www.gutenberg.org/files/7524/7524-h/7524-h.htm to Pocket using the Firefox extension or Android share feature, what ends up in my Pocket is the landing page, http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/7524?msg=welcome_stranger . I have had no problem saving the Conan the Barbarian books to Pocket in the past. What's different?